# Deleting multiple mysql rows from multiple tables with one statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

All I can find are answers with Joins and Inner Joins,

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM `Item` WHERE `ItemID`='$_POST[id]';
       DELETE FROM `Info` WHERE `Item_ItemID`='$_POST[id]';
   DELETE FROM `ListPics` WHERE `Item_ItemID`='$_POST[id]';";
```

This gives me an error.

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM `Info` WHERE 
`Item_ItemID`='1'; DELETE FROM `ListPics` WHERE `I' at line 2
```

I don't really understand how joins work, and I'm not even sure they apply I really just want to delete the 3 rows from the 3 tables with one statment.

Comment: You can't do that with mysql_query; you can with mysqli_multi_query, which lets you send through a semi-colon separated list of commands to perform. Alternatively, you can do this with database configurations, and set up `Info` to delete entries when the parent `$itemID` is deleted.

Comment: Maybe try a transaction.

Comment: Why does this have to be one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple queries using [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php); you can pass them in as a semi-colon separated list:

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM `ListPics` WHERE `Item_ItemID`='$_POST[id]';
       DELETE FROM `Info` WHERE `Item_ItemID`='$_POST[id]';
       DELETE FROM `Item` WHERE `ItemID`='$_POST[id]';";

mysqli_multi_query($dbConn, $sql)
```

I've swapped around the order of the deletes. Because the `ListPics and`Info`have a foreign key in them refering to`Item`, you need to delete those first, otherwise you'll get an error about violating the foreign key constraints.

Note that you can also do this with ON DELETE CASCADE in the database - using that, when you delete something from `Item`, anything that references `ItemID` as a foreign key is also removed for you. Thanks to Leonardo for the informative link.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete from multiple tables at once, via PHP. PHP can only run one statement at a time, and you cannot do deletes with a join.

Comment: So I need to create a loop?

Comment: *cough*mysqli_multi_query*cough* :D

Comment: I stand corrected - I had not seen that. Hopefully OP is using mysqli :)

Comment: @andrewsi I tried mysqli_multi_query but its spitting out foriegn key constainte errors

Comment: @DcHerrera - you need to reverse the order of the deletes, so the child tables are deleted first. You can't delete from `item` until `info` and `listPics` have no related rows.

Comment: @andrewsi hey that was it. if you want to throw up mysqli_multi_query as the answer I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to design you `Item` table, so that when you delete a record, it'll delete all of it's associations.

And then, and only then, you can use:

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM `Item` WHERE `ItemID`='$_POST[id]';
```

It all depends how your tables are designed, but you cand find some info [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)

Comment: SO an on delete event?

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain in my comment - could you explain a little more how to do it, because I can't for the life of me remember what to do!

Comment: @andrewsi it all depends of how are the tables designed, but [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) is some info

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right delimiter to separate the commands.  IN this case it appears that you are using ';' . 
Please make sure that that is the expected statement delimiter. You can change the delimiter too in a session. 
And as always try your command set in a command-line session to make sure it is syntactically correct before baking it in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ON DELETE CASCADE